# Apache Lucene boost document section

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am working on a project in Apache Lucene 7.2.1 and I want to change the scoring system for documents, so that the first part of a document (first 5 words) are twice more relevant than the rest of the document.

As an example:

doc1 = "one two three four five six"

doc2 = "six one two three four five"

query = "six"

The score for doc2 must be twice larger than the score for doc1.

Can you please help me achieve this? I know that in older versions of Lucene there was a setBoost method on Field, but in this version, there isn't one. Should the boost be set when a document is indexed, or when the query is made?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Boosting should be done while search-time. You're able to achieve this with a BoostQuery.

BoostQuery is Query class so you're able to combine this with other query types. An abstract example:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new BoostQuery(query1, 2f), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.add(new BoostQuery(query2, 1f), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

See more details for general scoring and boosting here:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#package.description

Comment: Hmm, nice idea with the BoostQuery. I can make a Query with a boost value of 3, considering only the first 10 words of each document, and another Query with a boost value of 1, considering the rest of the document. 

In the end, adding the 2 scores for each document to retrieve the final score... is this right? Or is there any class/method provided by Lucene which combines the scores of different queries?

Comment: BoostQuery is based on Query, so you're able to combine multiple queries depending on you're document structure. i will at an abstract example to the answer. Based on this you will receive the score directly, no need to adding scores.

Comment: I did as suggested (with SHOULD instead of MUST) and it's almost correct. What isn't ok now is that the score of doc2 in my example isn't exactly 2 times the score of doc1. I think it has something to do with the length of each part of the document.

Comment: can you provide how you're docs look like? what was your added score? 2f and 1f?

Comment: The docs are as I described in the question:

doc1 = "one two three four five six"

doc2 = "six one two three four five"

Yes, the first query (first 5 words) is boosted by 2.

Comment: so it's one field with multiple terms in it? StringField or TextField?

Comment: Each Document has 2 TextFields, one keeping the first 5 words of the document, and the other one the rest of the content.

Comment: ok. hmm well why do you exactly need a doubled score? scoring in detail is complex. so the question is can you life with this solution?